# 'No active compatible AVD's or devices found

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt, launch

I'm new with Eclipse ADT, and I tried to run an app on my tablet (a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1), but there is an error as below:

```
[2013-12-26 12:37:41 - SDK_Example] ------------------------------

[2013-12-26 12:37:41 - SDK_Example] Android Launch!

[2013-12-26 12:37:41 - SDK_Example] adb is running normally.

[2013-12-26 12:37:41 - SDK_Example] Performing com.metaio.Example.MainActivity activity launch

[2013-12-26 12:37:41 - SDK_Example] No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD.
```

Can anyone tell me why my device isn't found?

Comment: have u made and started any avd ?

Comment: can u use command prompt and  change ur derectory to android SDK platform tool directory (eg -  E:\Harsha\Applications\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools) and enter <<<adb devices>>> it will list ur connected devices and virtual devices

Answer (score 5):

So if you are using emulator then close it. 
In Eclipse select **Run > Run Configurations > Target > Always prompt to pick device > Run**.

Now select a a device from the list or a launch a new emulator. The next time you Run the project it should work.

Answer (score 4):

The error shows that the API level which your application having the compatible emulator for that API level does not exists. You need to create the emulator compatible to your application's api level.

**OR**

If your emulator is already started then You need to reset the ADB to make the emulator available. Go to `DDMS > In Device tab > Select Down arrow> Select Reset adb option.`

Check out the image 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Seems like your device is not getting detected by the ADB.

Check if you have **enabled USB debugging** in your tablet or not. Sometimes disconnecting and re-connecting the device also makes it work. Also bear in mind that the API level of your application should be supported by your device.

Answer (score 2):

This error message will appear , if there are no compatible android API in SDK is found. Try to update your eclipse with appropriate API. To update your API go to Window -> Android SDK Manager. Then choose required API version from Android SDK Manager window. Finally press install packages button .After required packages installation completed, create new AVD for your project and Run your project.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an emulator or use a device that is compatible with API target. i.e the device or emulator should have a android version that is compatible with your project.

Answer (score 0):

In `androidmanifest.xml` try to support the version from API level 8 onward

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

and even try to unable **USB debugging** in your mobile ..

Before to that you should have Mobile sync installed in the system...

once you try to edit the code in the project and even try to clean the project and run it ..,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had usb debugging set and  eclipse was running the app fine and then it stopped one day. I discovered, with the help of other comments here that my phone had to be set as a mass storage device otherwise it wouldn't work. Once I changed it from camera, or another setting to mass storage it worked. I must have played with the usb setting and changed it. The manual didn't mention that mass storage was necessary.